# Angular JS Initialize service with different parameter dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an app that when you select a project, it goes into the project section where it needs to load all the information and data about a project asynchronously.

I wanted to store all the data in a singleton service so I can access the data in all the project's subsections(project header, project footer, main menu, etc)

If user clicks a different project, it will need to re-initialize with different URL parameter (in this case, project_id).

```js
app.factory('ProjectService', function($http, project_id) {
var SERVICE = {
    async: function() {
        var promise = $http.get('SOME URL' + project_id).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        return promise;
    }
};
return SERVICE;
});
```

What is the best way to achieve this and how can I reinitialize the service with different URL parameters when user clicks a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/904r87k9/)

First of all, using a `factory` may be more suitable for your case.

You need to play with the deferred/promise manually. If the requested id is already loaded, resolve the deferred object immediately. Otherwise, send a HTTP request (in the demo I just used [an public API providing fake data](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)) and fetch the project information.

```
app.factory('ProjectFactory', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var myProject;
    return {
        project: function (id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            // If the requested id is fetched already, just resolve
            if (!id || (myProject && myProject.id === id)) {
                console.log('get from cache');
                deferred.resolve(myProject);
            } else {
                console.log('sending request...');
                $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id).success(function (response) {
                    myProject = response;
                    deferred.resolve(myProject);
                }).error(function (response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

To use this factory:

```
app.controller('JoyCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'ProjectFactory', function ($scope, $timeout, ProjectFactory) {
    ProjectFactory.project(1).then(function (project) {
        $scope.project = project;
        ProjectFactory.project(1).then(function (project) {
        });
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
    });
}]);
```

For your reference: [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: Wow, took me some time to understand what was going on, but it worked! Thanks alot!